# CreateTimerQueue for linux

Tags: c++, linux, timer

Anyone know if there is any function similar to CreateTimerQueue on linux? Or do I have to make my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use timer_gettime and timer_settime.  Lookup the page on [timer_create](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) to get a nice example

Answer (score 0):

Check out the boost::asio timers for a portable solution: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html

If you're already using a GUI toolkit (Qt, wxWidgets), then those usually have some kind of timer facility.